# Xcode9.3 supportedInterfaceOrientations performs incorrectly

Tags: ios, orientation, xcode9.2, xcode9.3

I running my code without any change in Xcode9.2 and Xcode9.3. Apparently, the device orientation perform incorrectly in Xcode9.3. SupportedInterfaceOrientations was called but the device still rotate to portrait. Anyone can help?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check ViewControllers hierarchy. Maybe you have some parent or child view controller who is accepting different rotation modes.